# Change color of push button

Tags: matlab, colors, qpushbutton

I am trying to create the game Battleship in MATLAB r2013. I want to change the color of a push button with a function (without clicking it) in order to understand when the PC hit my panel of ships. Does anyone have any idea how I can do this? I have tried with the command `set(myOwnBattleship.Apanel.tableA3,'BackgroundColor','k')` where the `Apanel` is the player's panel and `tableA3` is the button which I want to change color.

Comment: Are you sure that's the handle name of your button? Sounds more like a name for a table to me... So, what happens when you execute that line?

Comment: I am not sure,how can I find the name of my button my friend?when I am running the function,the PC hits the player's panel but the color doesn't change....Error in myOwnBattleship1>pcHits (line 1388)
        set(myOwnBattleship.Apanel.tableA22, 'BackgroundColor','r' )

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool like [findjobj-gui](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/findjobj-gui-display-container-hierarchy/) to look at your object hierarchy. I am not sure if it also gives you the matlab handles, but at least you see how things are nested which would enable you to find the right control.